# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module { AXIOS }

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-testing-library

Hello I changed my code from fetch to axios and when I run my tests I get this problem... Can anyone help me with that ?

---

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

```
> 1 | import axios from "axios";
```

---

Jest encountered an unexpected token

```
This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurred after axios update from 0.27.2 to 1.0.0. There is an opened [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5026), so probably this is going to be fixed soon. Meanwhile they're working on that, you can temporary fix it by setting up [transformIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) in jest config:

```
transformIgnorePatterns = ["node_modules/(?!axios)/"]
```

Answer (score 5):

For me helped the following `jest.config.js` setup:

```
transformIgnorePattern: [
 '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!axios)/'
]
```

alongside with

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^axios$': require.resolve('axios'),
}
```

Comment: just the second code block did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried what Andre suggested but it didn't work for me. After searching the issue comments I tried replacing the test script in my package.json with

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns\"node_modules/(?!axios)/\""
}
```

and it worked perfectly. Hope this helps! It was a frustrating issue.

Thank you Andre for providing the link to the github issue.